# How can this JS be Decoded?

Tags: javascript, encryption, decode

I have this code, but have no clue how to de-code it.
Can anyone help me with this or point me in the right direction?

Thanks a million in advance!

http://pastebin.com/ZvSSqyj3

Comment: The main points of obfuscation seem to be changed variable names and strings all at the front. I used this (gzipped, base64-encoded because of length) Python script to fix the latter issue: `H4sIANAv2lUCA2VQwWqEMBC9+xWDlySshC7toQh77U+olGjGbZZEZSbifn6jhtLSHJLw5s28N8+FZaYID56nwp1/wmJz8QvmBScpOK7jqB8sKhAkFBiGsS4gndERR7jBqAmN9W5CqY4C4S88YT/E/W2OW7vJ4lOKRqj6BCgjnVCXa1dwTMCdU9duTfvZWJaZiYs3A0oqW1FWUIpSVbDzh3j7MJ5RFdkBoea1lyTa/vPl+WZe39tGtvai2i6t403orYFQnxJ2DQvLrNu4Kcqg7zSvi7wq1SWJfaj6H43FIcez/Y1Hb+Risnm0fQMNhmouaAEAAA==`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that type of obfuscation, you are going to want to use [JSDetox](http://www.relentless-coding.com/projects/jsdetox). Install it in a Virtual Machine, on a Linux distro, I recommend Ubuntu.

You want to do it in a Virtual Machine to avoid any issues with malicious code.

[This site](http://www.kahusecurity.com/2014/javascript-deobfuscation-tools-redux/) breaks down several different types of obfuscation and tools to defeat them.

Comment: I can't seem to get JSDetox installed :( Will look further - Thanks for your response, I'll let you know if this worked :)

Comment: @coderguyNL what was the trouble? Did you get any errors along the way that I might help with?

Comment: I just couldnt get it installed, neither could a developer friend of mine. Any idea how else I can get this decoded?

Comment: Well, since you are installing this now you probably tried installing the latest Ruby. JSDetox is only compatible with Ruby 1.8/1.9/2.0 and 2.1 as per the [Install Docs](http://relentless-coding.org/projects/jsdetox/install).